# Two clicks to open the navigation menu in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I use a [divi WordPress theme](https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/). I added some javascript code so that the navigation menu on the tablet and phone closes when a user clicks out of the menu.

But now I have another **problem**,

> **User needs to click twice on the navigation menu to open**

*Code Snippet*

```
<script>

window.addEventListener ('mouseup', function (event) {
    var box = document.getElementById ('mobile_menu');

    if (event.target !== box && event.target.parentNode !== box)
        box.style.display = 'none';
    }
});

</ script>
```

Comment: You have lot of mistakes in your code. There should be no space between `!` and `=`. Also add your html code

Comment: i fix that but still not working

Comment: can you provide a working jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: @doki add your html code too. So that others can reproduce this issue

Comment: https:// paste.ofcode.org/TeyKJZqWCBWvSdAYY4FMmB